# how implement google maps route in c# with devexpress?

Tags: c#, google-maps, visual-studio-2013, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a data (latitude and longitude) in my oracle database and I would like to draw a route using google maps (winform - devexpress). I was reading about mapcontrol but It's not connect with google maps It's only use bing maps or open street maps. Could you please help me to do that? thanks in advance.

Comment: have you seen https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Google Maps has no support to Windows platform.

However, you can insert a WebView and create a page using the [Javascript API with Shapes Polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polylines); the [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/intro#PathPoints) for a map image; or even the [Embed Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#directions_mode) (using direction).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea. I'm doing follow your opinion.